# Space after named argument colon

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

I am looking for a PHP CS Fixer rule that requires a single space after a named argument, going from this:

```php
array_key_exists(
    key:'test',
    array:$array,
);
```

to this:

```php
array_key_exists(
    key: 'test',
    array: $array,
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule [`single_space_after_construct`](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/v3.3.2/doc/rules/language_construct/single_space_after_construct.rst) is what you are looking for, it has an option `named_argument` which is enabled by default.

So either use it with default (`true` in config) or add `named_argument` to `constructs` array.